# How can I draw an area and plot a line from columns of df?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following df

| index | Alive Past & Future | Alive Past | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 800 | 1000 | 0.8 |
| 1/2/2020 | 200 | 400 | 0.5 |
| 1/3/2020 | 300 | 300 | 1.0 |
| 1/4/2020 | 400 | 800 | 0.5 |
| 1/5/2020 | 500 | 2000 | 0.25 |

Here is the code I am using to draw an area chart
`df.plot.area(stacked=False)`
[image]

Is there a way to make the first 2 columns be as an area chart and the third column be drawn as a line? Also is it possible that the areas and the line have different y-axis (left and right) as they have different magnitudes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
# plot area with first two columns
ax = df.iloc[:,:2].plot.area()

# line plot with 3rd column
df.plot(y='%', secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image: img]